# Bind Mount & Volumes: Files do not end up in the container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am sweating over a weird problem. I am mounting a folder from the host machine to the container (only for development). The folder is called `dj_docker` and has a folder `dj_docker/media` with some `.pdf` files that need to end up in the container and must be accessible for other containers via the volume `media_volume`. However, as soon as I map the subdirectory `/media` to the volume (the bind mount as well as the volume now include the folder `/media`) all the contents of the folder disappear in the container. The folder is empty.

**Simplified docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  restapi:
    volumes: 
      - media_volume:/usr/src/dj/media
      - ./dj_docker:/usr/src/dj/
volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

If I omit the volume in the docker-compose file, the .pdf files are visible and present in the container:

```
    volumes: 
      - ./dj_docker:/usr/src/dj/
```

**Is there a way to still use a bind mount as well as the volume with me keeping the files in the container?**

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

# set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/dj

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/dj/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
VOLUME /usr/src/dj/media

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/dj/entrypoint.sh

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/dj/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Don't you have duplicate paths? dj folder contains media folder which gets overrided by the media_volume

Comment: Yes, I suspect this is what happens (although expected behaviour would have been a merge) ... but I still need to get the files from my local machine in the container/volume

Comment: Well this is not possible to merge... You need to have different paths for the volumes

Comment: @Xen_mar Sorry for the inconvenience. I agree with the solution with 2 different paths. If you haven't done so you can automate it further by adding something like "cp -R /usr/src/dj/media/* /pdfs/" in your entrypoint.sh. Where /pdfs is the container mount directory for the external volume (- media_volume:/pdfs). This would update your volume at each restart of the service, no need for manual actions inside the container. Hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to still use a bind mount as well as the volume with me keeping the files in the container?

No, this isn't possible.

This is the same as ordinary Un*x **mount**(8) (and in fact if you poke around with low-level tools you'll see filesystem mounts in a Docker setup).  A volume mount completely hides everything that was in the directory before.  If you have layered mounts like this, the Docker sorts them before applying any, and the innermost directory mount hides the contents in that directory in the next outermost mount.

The easiest thing to change here is probably the container-side directory holding this data.  I might pick a root directory path like `/media`, outside your application's install tree.  Set the location through an environment variable (it is different in your non-Docker development environment).  Copy the seed content there on startup if it doesn't exist (it will not be hidden by a volume mount now).

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your answer. I have tried your approach and got it working. Its a bit of a bummer, because my dockerized dev-server uses hot-reloads and now it wont be possible to do this with updated static files since I have to restart the service to copy now static files to the image. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DavidMaze I was genuinely convinced my solution would work since i could swear I solved a similar problem like this before. But since I cannot prove it (and I tried) I will admit you are right. I still don't agree that VOLUME is useless, but indeed it doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can have both host and named volumes, but there's a trick to make it work. This article should solve your problem: https://jdlm.info/articles/2019/09/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html.